# How can I clone an Elastic Beanstalk environment from the AWS SDK for Java?

Tags: java, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-sdk

I need to clone an Elastic Beanstalk environment from the AWS SDK for Java.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134502/1535071) answer explaining how to create an environment but I can't find any example or documentation showing how to clone an environment.

I found a `clone` method for `CreateEnvironmentRequest` but according to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/model/CreateEnvironmentRequest.html) it clones the `CreateEnvironmentRequest` object, not the environment.

[image]

Comment: May be you should first create a http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/api/API_CreateConfigurationTemplate.html and then create needed environment from this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't exactly clone an environment with the Java SDK for AWS, my approach is to simply create a new environment every time, you can do something like this:

1. Upload your deployment file (war, zip whatever) to S3
2. Create a version for your deployment linking to the previously uploaded file

   ```
   private CreateApplicationVersionRequest createApplicationVersion() {
       return new CreateApplicationVersionRequest()
               .withApplicationName("The app name")
               .withAutoCreateApplication(true)
               .withSourceBundle(new S3Location("bucket_name", deployedArtifactId))
               .withVersionLabel("a number for the version");
   }
   ```
3. You go and look for the latest version of your stack

   ```
   private void getLatestStackSolutionVersion() {
       ListAvailableSolutionStacksResult response = beanstalkClient.listAvailableSolutionStacks();
       for (int i = 0; i < response.getSolutionStacks().size(); i++) {
           if (response.getSolutionStacks().get(i).contains("Java 8") {
               stackName = response.getSolutionStacks().get(i);
               break;
           }
       }    
   }
   ```
4. Configure the properties of your environment, system properties and everything.

   ```
   private Collection<ConfigurationOptionSetting> setEnvironmentProperties() {
       Collection<ConfigurationOptionSetting> configurationOptionSettings = new HashSet<>();
       configurationOptionSettings.add(new ConfigurationOptionSetting("aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", "InstanceType", "t2.medium"));
       configurationOptionSettings.add(new ConfigurationOptionSetting("aws:ec2:vpc", "VPCId","thevpcid");
       configurationOptionSettings.add(new ConfigurationOptionSetting("aws:ec2:vpc", "Subnets", "thesubnets");
       configurationOptionSettings.add(new ConfigurationOptionSetting("aws:ec2:vpc", "ELBSubnets", "theelbsubnets");
       configurationOptionSettings.add(new ConfigurationOptionSetting("aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment", "ANOTHER_PROPERTY", "a value"));
       return configurationOptionSettings;
   }
   ```
5. Create the environment with everything ready.

   ```
   public void deployCreatingEnvironment() {
       getLatestStackSolutionVersion();
       beanstalkClient.createApplicationVersion(createApplicationVersion());
       beanstalkClient.createEnvironment(setupNewEnvironment());
   }
   ```

Voilà! It is like cloning everytime, hope this works for you.

Answer (score 2):

There has been an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/367) opened for this as for now the clone operation is not possible from the sdk. If you're interested you might want to reopen the ticket and provide your reason.

The other possibility is to call the `eb` cli from your Java to run the clone of your environment.